# CoreOS hostname on reboot

Tags: vps, hostname, coreos

Recently, I created a CoreOS droplet on DigitalOcean. Everything works well, except for the fact that I'm not able to change the hostname of my VPS. When I change the hostname to what it should be using `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname myhostname.org` (the documented way of doing so), it indeed changes the hostname system-wide (e.g. `/etc/hostname` reflects the new hostname). However, when I reboot the VPS, the hostname gets reverted to what it used to be.

It might not be a coincidence, but the hostname always reverts to the original name of the droplet. I've already changed that name about one week ago to the correct hostname. I have read stories about DHCP influencing the hostname on reboot, but I'm not able to find a solution to avoid that on CoreOS.

How to change the hostname of CoreOS in such a way that it will remain the same after a reboot?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On DigitalOcean (and some other cloud providers; Openstack for example) they're providing metadata on each boot of the machine (either provided via cloud-config  or via the options you provided in the DigitalOcean web interface).  When you bestowed a name on the droplet/VM you signified to the metadata service that you wanted the hostname to be called that value.  cloud-config is honoring the request put forth by the DigitalOcean metadata service.  This is actually a design pattern and operating outside of it would me much like trying to *avoid* uing convention over configuration in Rails.  You can do it, but you're only making things harder on yourself.

Inside the DigitalOcean web interface you can rename the droplet Select Droplet->"Settings"->"Rename"

As to why the option in  previous answer does not exist, CoreOS does not ship Python [cloud-init](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-cloudinit/blob/master/Documentation/cloud-config.md) had to be re-written in a compiled language (hence it being written in [Go](http://golang.org/).  To view the metadata on DigitalOcean log into the host and run the command:

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/metadata/v1/user-data
```

Comment: The suggested curl request gives an empty result... However, when I replaced `user-data` with `hostname`, I got what I expected: the wrong hostname, even though I renamed it through the droplet settings (something I did prior to asking this question). I guess it's a DigitalOcean issue. Thanks!